# Lambda Probe equivalent for Tomcat 7

Tags: lambda, tomcat7

I've used Lambda Probe for Tomcat 6 but it does not work in Tomcat 7.

Is there an equivalent monitor for Tomcat?

http://www.lambdaprobe.org doesn't even work anymore.

Answer (score 10):

Check [PSI Probe](https://github.com/psi-probe/psi-probe) (now on GitHub)

Comment: sorry for the off the topic.Do you know how to view local_access_log file in prbe

Comment: @SpringLearner Sorry I have not used it for a long time (updated the link)

Comment: Ok ,do you know if its possible to view user created log files(for example abc.log) present inside logs folder in probe? The reason for asking is as per [this article](http://www.techstacks.com/howto/configure-access-logging-in-tomcat.html) I have configured.Now I want to see local_access_file in probe.So how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

[JavaMelody](http://javamelody.googlecode.com) is also a similar and opensource tool which works in Tomcat 7

Comment: I believe JavaMelody is for monitoring while PSI Probe is more for substituting Tomcat manager (deployment, etc.)